# Finding examples for linear transformations with certain properties

Tags: linear-transformations, examples-counterexamples

**1)**

Define a linear transformation $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ with $ker(f)=f(\mathbb{R}^2)$

**Solution**

At first this was not easy for me to wrap my head around but after some thought it seems simple: Everything that the function outputs is mapped to 0 if it is fed again into the function. So I put:

$f(\begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\end{bmatrix}) = \begin{bmatrix}r_2\\0\end{bmatrix}$ for all $r = \begin{bmatrix}r_1\\r_2\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^2$

**2)**

Define a linear transformation $f$ so that $f \circ f=f$. $f \neq 0$ and $f \neq id_{\mathbb{R}^2}$

**Solution**

$f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$

Because $(f \circ f)(x) = f(f(x)) = f(x) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$

Are these solutions and the notation correct?

Answer (score 2):

The first one is correct, the second is not as $f$ is not linear. Remember that linear mappings fulfil $f(0) = 0$ (where $0$ is to be understood as a vector).

**Hint for 2):** Set up
$$
f(x_1, x_2) := 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c& d
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 \\ x_2 
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Calculate
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c& d
\end{pmatrix}^2 = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a^2 + bc & ab + bd \\ ca + cd & cb + d^2
\end{pmatrix} \overset{!}{=}
\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}
.
$$
Now choose an adequate combination of $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}$.